# How to insert a 1 row into a dataframe for every ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` that contains purchase data. Each row has a different item in the `item` column, but naturally the purchase id's in `purchaseId` stays the same across the same purchase. How can I insert a row for each `purchaseId` that contains the value in the `age` column as seen in `df2` but in the `item` column?

```
df

purchaseId     item      age  
    22         apples    35
    22         coffee    35
    22         wipes     35
    53        tomatoes   23
    53         sugar     23
    53         tea       23


df2

purchaseId     item      age  
    22         apples    35
    22         coffee    35
    22         wipes     35
    22         35        35
    53        tomatoes   23
    53         sugar     23
    53         tea       23
    53         23        23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with new `DataFrame` created by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last sorting index by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
#necesary default index
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df2 = (pd.concat([df, 
                  df.drop_duplicates('purchaseId', keep='last')
                    .assign(item = lambda x: x['age'])])
         .sort_index(kind='mergesort', ignore_index=True))
print (df2)
   purchaseId      item  age
0          22    apples   35
1          22    coffee   35
2          22     wipes   35
3          22        35   35
4          53  tomatoes   23
5          53     sugar   23
6          53       tea   23
7          53        23   23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'purchaseID':[22,22,22,53,53,53],
               'item':['apple','coffe','wipes',
                       'tomatoes','sugar','tea'],
               'age':[35,35,35,23,23,23]})

df = df.append(df.groupby(['purchaseID','age'], as_index=False)['age'].max(), ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='purchaseID')
df['item'].fillna(df['age'], inplace=True)
```